# When should I use square brackets and when should I use parentheses?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy, tuples

Do we have any difference between

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

and

```
a = np.array((1,2,3))
```

?

With both inputs, I am getting the following output when I try this:

```
print(a)
print(a.ndim)
print(a.shape)
print(type(a))
```

#### Output

```
[1 2 3]
1
(3,)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Is there any difference between them? What is the best syntax for calling `numpy.array:`?

If they are the same, then is there a reason why people prefer one over the other?

Comment: One is converting a list to array and the other is converting a tuple to an array.

Comment: In Python `[]` is used for lists, and for indexing. `()` are used for tuples, and function calls.  In `np.array( )`, the outer `()` a function call.  `np.array` can create an array from either a list or a tuple.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I made the change to the title.

Comment: There is one little gotcha: `np.array((1))` is _not_ the same as `np.array([1])`. To form a tuple of length 1 use `(1,)` -> `np.array((1,))`

Comment: Thank you for the reply Paul. Lesson learned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets `[1,2,3]` make a `list`.  Round brackets `(1,2,3)` make a `tuple`.  The main difference is that a list can be resized and modified, whereas a tuple is immutable.

There is no practical difference in anonymous expressions like `np.array([1,2,3])`.  You can use either form with equal correctness and effect.  The square-brackets form is perhaps more conventional.

Comment: Thank you John, this was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @LunaHK: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem, you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left.